# Homebrew Portable Ruby Error macOS 10.14.6

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

Homebrew suddenly stopped working, when i run any brew command i get following output:

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-portable-ruby/portable-ruby-2.6.3_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/<user>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/portable-ruby-2.6.3_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/vendor-install.sh: line 123: /usr/bin/cut: cannot execute binary file
Error: Checksum mismatch.
Expected: b065e5e3783954f3e65d8d3a6377ca51649bfcfa21b356b0dd70490f74c6bd86
  Actual: 
 Archive: /Users/<user>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/portable-ruby-2.6.3_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
Error: Failed to upgrade Homebrew Portable Ruby!
```

I already tried to remove the file portable-ruby-2.6.3_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz but it doesn't work and i couldn't find any helpful information about this error on Google.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error message says that the file `/usr/bin/cut` cannot be executed. So, the first thing I would try, if my computer tells me that a file cannot be executed is to execute that file.

Comment: can you also attach your `brew doctor` and `brew config` output? Thanks!

Comment: Any brew command does output the above, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that I can think of for your situation.

- Your output has yosemite identifier, to be clear, MacOS Yosemite is actually `10.10.x`, it is not in the current/latest homebrew support list, and also different from 10.14 Mojave in your problem title. So if you are actually using Mojave, you can keep your brew up to date and reinstall ruby.
- The latest Ruby formula is actually `2.7.x`, you might want to reinstall/upgrade (`brew reinstall ruby`/`brew upgrade ruby`).

In all, if you still run into an issue, please attach the outputs of `brew config` and `brew doctor` for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Try `brew update-reset` and then try `brew upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

It's set portable-ruby-2.6.3_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz was already downloaded so I removed it and it went through henceforth.